# Which domestic animal would pose the greatest threat to humanity during zoopocalypse?

Tags: apocalypse, domestication, quantum, mutation

Set in the modern days, one night the sky is suddenly lit up in a mysterious bright blue glows that fades off almost immediately. It seems that somehow the event caused a mutation in one of the protein found in many domestic animal including those in cages. The mutated protein contains free radicals but usually stay dormant but once daybreaks, their body begins to produce more of these proteins and the blue wavelength of light would energise the free radical so that the electrons tend to entangled into pairs. Unfortunately this entangled state is prone to upset by the magnetic field generate from our household appliances leading the poor animal to suddenly go berserk and exhibit aggressive behaviour. Given this scenario which pet would pose the greatest threat to us?

Bonus: Any one who can resolve the mechanism behind these bizarre phenomenon with good hypothesis gets to name the mutated protein. (reply to StarfishPrime's comment)

Comment: It'll be a challenge to find a protein expressed in domestic animals, but not wild ones or people ;-)

Comment: Rats and mice--sheer numbers

Comment: If insects are also an option, then i would say: [Mosquitos][1] that transmit diseases, e.g. malaria, zika or yellow fever. Right now they are living in certain climates and heights. If they could spread freely, they could decimate the populatioin pretty quickly.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anopheles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dogs have three factors going for them:
Most breeds are capable of seriously injuring or killing their owners.
They are abundant and in close proximity.
They are bred from pack hunters. Ganging up on their prey would come naturally.

While cats are predators as well their size makes it harder to kill a human, they'd have to act as a coordinated team. They have the numbers, but not the inclination. They'd probably cause a lot of injury, but less fatal ones.

Farm animals like pigs, cattle or horses can be lethal but aren't in contact with a lot of people. Also most are more likely to try to flee then attack - behavior more beneficial to a herbivore.

Most other pets are either relatively harmless or to exotic to be widespread danger.

Bonus: what do sewer rats do? If you look for troublesome rodents they are your prime candidates.

Comment: Can you also list their estimated kill counts?

Comment: Almost a silly question wasn't it (umm almost? I retract that word), dogs really are the only possible answer, for proximity (read opportunity) it has to be a pet & no other pet of sufficient size comes close to matching their numbers.

Comment: Not to mention once a pig starts feed GTFO of the way they can chew through bone easily and basically go into a like feeding frenzy.

Comment: @Stupidzombiet True, but people who keep pigs *know* that. People with pet dogs don't take the same kind of precautions.

Comment: I went over and over this question. Dogs are by far the greatest threat, in my opinion. They are the loyal beasts given full rein to our kingdom. If they turned assassin, we’d take them out quickly, but the loss of life in the first couple weeks would be devastating.  The good news: now you can limit your protein search to something that only shows up in dogs.

Comment: And let’s not forget the emotional damage that canine betrayal would generate!

Answer (score 2):

My hippo answer made me think of another animal in the south right now they are having a huge problem with, or were I'm not sure now but,

WIld boars. 
Like hundreds maybe thousands just practically eating everything in their path. Im talking people going out in trucks and flying in helicopters shooting them and the population still does not drop.

And when they come upon humans they can go from 0 to 60 real fast. A man in the deep south actually got mauled by a wild pig in his house. What are you gonna do against an animal with tusks that weighs 300 / 400 pounds of SOLID MUSCLE.

Imagine if a horde of pigs went crazy...

https://www.helibacon.com/wild-hog-problem/

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/a-plague-of-pigs-in-texas-73769069/

Answer (score 0):

This will probably get barried but I have to say it cuz no one else will:

Hippos.

Hippos are one of the most territorial aggressive animals and dangerous animals in the animal kingdom.  You wouldn't think they would be, but they are. They are like the honey badgers of the vegetarian animal family. Hippos dont care. Now imagine if they went wild...thinking all the zoo's that keep wild hippos

Comment: But people do not keep hippos in close proximity to themselves. In the west, they are only in zoos, and would have a hard time escaping. Even if they did escape, most zoos only have a few, and they would quickly be shot by police or armed civilians.